# How to organize Resource Dictionary files (Style, Brush) etc in an Application?

Tags: wpf, styles

Which is best way to organize resource files in an application? Currently in my application my resources are added inside an ResourceLib project which has this structure:

Color [folder]

- ColorTheme1.xaml
- ColorTheme2.xaml
- ColorTheme2.xaml 
  .
  .
  .

StyleResource[Folder]

- Button.xaml
- ToggleButton.xaml
- TextBox.xaml
- ListBox.xaml
- Treeview.xaml
  .
  .
  .
  .

HeaderStyle [folder]

- HeaderStyle1.xaml
- HeaderStyle2.xaml
  .
  .
  .
  etc

This list will keep on increasing as the day progresses.

In the App.xaml i am referencing this Library and merging these dictionary file for one time initialization. DynamicResource is used to support theme facility.

Will there be any performance impact if continue with this structure?. Is there any advantage or performance impact if i put all these xaml in to one resource name (Style.xaml)?

What are the performance implications of a Style.xaml with 5000 lines versus splitting same into 10 different xaml files?

Finally, which is the best or accepted method?

Comment: Consistency and organization will likely trump any neglible performance impact.  YMMV.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The company I work for does a lot of WPF and Silverlight work.  I've developed an organization structure that we now use on all projects.  That structure and write-up can be found here:

http://projekt202.com/blog/2010/xaml-organization/

Comment: @JeffMcLean -- I use this link ALL THE TIME--thank you so much for providing it. However, do you mind sharing how you reference your brush resources from within the Style ResourceDictionaries (i.e. within NamedStyles Resource Dictionaries) in the same project? A million thanks to you already.

Comment: Hi, I have noticed that you are holding brushes in separate resource files. Lets say that there is one particular brush that is used in ALL other resources (named, default, custom controls, etc). This means that we will need to merge brushes into every other resource dictionary that uses at least one brush. Is it wise to load 200 brushes into a resource dictionary that requires only a few brushes?

Comment: I've just searched my rather large project which has over 200 styles - would it be right then that I'd now have 200 resource dictionaries with one style in each?

Comment: First of all, thanks Jeff for the "organization" link. - What this blog post does not answer is the question: how to include the styles in other sub-projects? I organize my solution into one main project (with app.xaml referencing the themes), one theme project (which includes all style resources) and for every "entity" a separate project, e. g. customers, orders etc. How do I include the style resources in the sub projects? Of course I have a reference to the assembly in the project, but do I have to repeat the reference to the styles resource dictionary in each and every user control?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you will gain any performance as everything gets piled up in one big dictionary object anyways. Even if there is any gain at all, don't go for it. The maintainability you get in having different xaml is hard to trade off.

Having said this `DynamicResource` is a performance hungry operation, you might have to `Freeze` brushes and images wherever possibe. Add:
`xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"`

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderBrush" Color="Black" PresentationOptions:Freeze="True"/>
```

Comment: Any resources or tips for knowing when it's good/okay to freeze and when it might not be?

Comment: Unless its dynamic resource I normally freeze all my brushes and images.